# Method rename_column does not rename the column in DB

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-migrations

**Solved!**

> Thanks to all so much. It seems was a conflict of the migration
>   versions. I just deleted last records from the scheme_migrations table
>   related with the column renaming. Also i deleted all migrations files
>   in db/migrations related with the renaming.

I have a table `products_images`:

```
class CreateProductsImages < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :products_images, id: false do |t|
      t.references :product
      t.references :image
      t.integer :position
    end
    add_index :products_images, [:product_id, :image_id]
    add_index :products_images, [:image_id, :product_id]
  end
end
```

When I have tried to start the migration to rename a column `position` to `priority` rails made migration without any errors. But no changes in DB table `products_images` were applied. Of course I could delete the column and create new one with another name. Just a curiosity - why? DB is SQLite.
Migrations of renaming:
variant 1

```
class RenamePositionToPriority < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    rename_column :products_images, :position, :priority
  end
end
```

variant 2:

```
class RenamePositionToPriority < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    #rename_column :products_images, :position, :priority
    change_table :products_images do |t|
      t.rename :position, :priority
    end
  end
end
```

**rake db:rollback** outputs:

```
DL is deprecated, please use Fiddle
==  RenamePositionToPriority: reverting =======================================
-- rename_column(:products_images, :priority, :position)
rake aborted!
An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

Missing column products_images.priorityC:in `migrate'
Tasks: TOP => db:rollback
```

Comment: can i send you the migration file

Comment: have you did the `db:migrate`. is seed you've begun of *rollback*

Comment: @Малъ Скрылевъ, yes, i did

Comment: is seems the db says in old status. make sure that the current structore of db has `priority` column using db console interface

Comment: @Малъ Скрылевъ sqlite> .header on
sqlite> select * from 'products_images
product_id  image_id    position    id
----------  ----------  ----------  --
50          19          1           1
51          19          1           8
51          20          2           9

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Step 1:** rails g migration RenameColumn

**Step 2:** before rake db:migrate open migration file on /db folder

class RenameColumn < ActiveRecord::Migration

```
 def self.up
   rename_column :products_images, :position, :priority
 end

 def self.down
    rename_column :products_images, :priority, :position
end
```

end

**Step 3:** rake db:migrate

Comment: Yes, it works! But why? May be empty method `change` affected to the behavior and its should be deleted. Thank you! But i can`t vote up -- someone took 2 my points :/ Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

class RenamePositionToPriority < ActiveRecord::Migration

def self.up
    rename_column :products_images , :position, :priority
    rename_column :products_images , :position, :priority
  end

def self.down
    rename_column :products_images , :position , :priority
    rename_column :products_images , :position , :priority
  end
end

can you please try this migration

Comment: class RenamePositionToPriority < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    rename_column :products_images , :position, :priority
  end
  def self.down
    rename_column :products_images , :priority , :position
  end
end

Comment: I have tried that but got a same result: D:\_web\test1>rake db:migrate 
DL is deprecated, please use Fiddle
==  RenamePositionToPriority: migrating =======================================
==  RenamePositionToPriority: migrated (0.0000s) ==============================

Comment: The column name `position` of the table `products_images` in DB is old

Comment: hye plz delete all migration related to this Perform a rake db:migrate VERSION=XXX on all environments, to the version before the one I want to delete.
Delete the migration file manually.
If there are pending migrations (i.e., the migration I removed was not the last one), I just perform a new rake db:migrate again


and then create new one
def self.up rename_column :products_images , :position, :priority rename_column :products_images , :position, :priority end

def self.down rename_column :products_images , :position , :priority rename_column :products_images , :position , :priority end end

Comment: Apparently it was a conflict of migrations. Thank you. All works fine! I will update the post.

Comment: Hope so it was help for you

Answer (score 0):

Is there any chance what you could 'change' migration code after it was run? Just to clarify couple of things: Rails has no way to 'remember' a set of changes you've made by migrations. It just creates table called `schema_migrations` with `version` column in it. Basically, this table contains a list of versions (which identify a migration).

Comment: Unlikely. Every time i just delete last record in `schema_migration` =)

Comment: What do you mean by 'just delete last record in schema_migration'?

Comment: Every time when i run rake db:migrate(note, with no errors) and see that renaming is not effected. I can`t apply rake db:rollback cuz rake could not find `priority` column.